# Why am i getting certain errors and wrong outputs?

Tags: c

I have this task to get the constant value between the inputs of an array.
How would i go about it? Ive used a selection sorting algorithm and searched for the value but I know thats the wrong method.

Comment: When you enter 25 values, `templength` isn't set. It's also never initialised and therefore has an undefined garbage value. You don't need `templength`: `break` out of the loop and return `lcv`.

Comment: But, in my getdata function, i did initialize templength, and I set it to the lcv when the lcv index value is -1. I have to return that value to use in the other UDFs. Im sorry, I do not understand what you are pointing out at.

Comment: @skyblade1234 what is `templength` if the user enters 25 values, *none* of which are `-1` ?

Comment: No, you don't initialise it. `int templength;` declares a local variable with undefined value. You set it when -1 is entered, but in the special case that 25 numbers are given, the variable isn't set. Try it out and print the return value of `getdataset`.

Comment: if(dataset[lcv] == -1 || lcv == 24)
    {
      templength = lcv.

Comment: Note when I enter `1 2 3 -1` the program reports `3`.

Comment: @skyblade1234 The point we made earlier was, what's wrong with [just doing something like this](https://pastebin.com/U8JyVQLa)?

Comment: I cant use break statements in if else constructs @WhozCraig

Comment: Do you mean the task forbids it?

Comment: @M Oehm, How would i change the code such that I take into consideration the 25 values then? Do  i have to change the if statement?

Comment: @Weather Vane, Yes, My course standard prohibits it. Unfortunately, I was not given a page with all the course standards else I would have pasted it here.

Comment: `int templength;` --> `int templength = LENGTH;`

Comment: I set my templength to 25, now it works thanks, but I guess my getconstantvalue function is wrong because I am getting errors from that.

Comment: @ BLUEPIXY, oh didnt see that thanks anyways

Comment: I have to say, that's nuts, A course where input validation like checking the results of `scanf` is apparently optional, but comprehendible code is off limits.  For that matter, you could just load up the continuation condition with the entire loop logic [like **this**](https://pastebin.com/6V3SUT6x). Anyway, glad you have something that works now.

Comment: By now, there's a good answer for your second problem. The problem with your code is that it goes on checking when it has found that two differences don't match. In that case, you should return 0 immediately. (In yourexample, the mismatch is decetcted, but later "corrected" again by constant differences at the end of the array.)

Answer (score 2):

First, the 25 items. The first comment is correct, if you enter the maximum number of items, templength will not be set. Tracing trough the code step by step will show this.

Regarding the bug with the output. I would avoid using too many offsets in the array index. It makes the code harder to understand, and certainly harder to debug. In this case the offsets will also give problems with very short arrays as pointed out in the comments. Why not try something like:

```
int findconstant(int dataset[], int templength)
{
    int lcv;
    int constantvalue;
    if (templength <= 1) {
        return 0;
    }
    constantvalue = dataset[1] - dataset[0];
    for (lcv = 2; lcv < templength ; lcv++) {
        if ((dataset[lcv] - dataset[lcv-1]) != constantvalue) {
            return 0;
        }
    }
    return constantvalue;
}
```

It's shorter, easier to read, understand and debug.

Comment: The case where `templength == 1` is missing.

Comment: Yes that did it, thank you, I am going to try and modify the code so that it is easier to follow. For the first if statement, when you say return 0, does that mean the constantvalue is set  to 0? What does the return 0 mean? Ive never used it inside loops or constructs before

Comment: @BLUEPIXY : if templength == 1, the loop will not be executed, leading to the correct answer

Comment: @skyblade1234: Returning early from a function is a great way to make code shorter and more concise. In this case, you used 0 to indicate that no constant was found, so when these cases are detected, just end the function indicating that no constant can be found (0).

Comment: `constantvalue = dataset[1] - dataset[0];` : if `templength == 1`,  `dataset[1]` should not be used. Of course the result is incorrect.